# Enumerating observableArray in knockout casting to string?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Again, seems like a brain fart on my side. Trying to make sample operation by looping through all of the objects in array and changing observable property on those objects:

```
var sss = vm.tripData();
                for (var sh2 in sss) {
                    sh2.isVisible(false);
                }
```

`sss` contains array of objects, I can see it in VS2012 locals - this is what I need. I declared `sss` just to see what I'm trying to enumerate. Inside loop first `sh2` contains string `"0"` Why? I guess it's some javascript thing (I'm from c# background).. I expect sh2 to be my object.

EDIT:

This is what I see in debugger:

[image: sss object]

[image: sh2 string]

Comment: Have you tried debugging and see what `sss` contains? could it be that it actually contains strings and not the object you are expecting?

Comment: This is what throws me off. I do see array of my objects as it should be. Edited to show debugger output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue is that for...in loops you over the keys to properties of an object, rather than values of the object.

So if you have an object like

```
var x = {
    a: "A",
    b: "B"
}
```

`for...in` will spit out `'a'` and `'b'`. Since arrays are objects, `for...in` with an array will give you something very similar: A string for each index into the array. So, with `var a= [1, 2, 3]`, `for...in` of `a` will result in `'0', '1', '2'`, rather than `1, 2, 3`.

Use a construct like below to do what you want, instead.

```
var sss = vm.tripData();
for (var i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
    var sh2 = sss[i];
    sh2.isVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that `for...in` iterates over the `keys` of the properties on an object, and not the `values`, which is why the current value of `sh2` is, in fact, `"0"`.